# Redirect Amazon Connect calls to phone number

Tags: amazon-web-services

I do not have the possibility to use web browser to pick-up inbound calls in Amazon Connect. When I try to set answer option to redirect phone call I can pick numbers from prefix drop-down only from a few countries (US, UK, IE, IT, FR) although AWS list outgoing phone charges to all countries in EU. Also from callcenter agent browser page I have the same issue, I can manually dial only to US, UK, IE, IT, FR.

Please help me understand if other countries are supported both for redirected inbound calls to agent mobile phone and also for placing outbound calls.

[image: Only these outbound options available]

Thank you

Comment: I think that may help https://aws.amazon.com/chime/faq/voice-connector/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but Chime won't fix my problems because I need inbound calling into EU countries (Chime supports US only) and also I need call recording in a simple turn on solution. (not available out of the box in Chime)